# How to efficiently remove elements of one array from another

Tags: python, nlp, data-analysis

I'm doing an analysis of a text corpus with about 135k documents (several pages per document), and a vocabulary of about 800k words. I noticed that something like half of the vocabulary is words with a frequency of 1 or 2, so I want to remove them.

So I'm running something like this:

```
remove_indices = np.array(index_df[index_df['frequency'] <= 2]['index']).astype(int)

for file_name in tqdm(corpus):
    content = corpus[file_name].astype(int)
    content = [index for index in content if index not in remove_indices]
    corpus[file_name] = np.array(content).astype(np.uint32)
```

Where `corpus` looks something like:

```
{
    'filename1.txt': np.array([43, 177718, 3817, ...., 28181]).astype(np.uint32),
    'filename2.txt': ....
}
```

and each word was previously encoded to a positive integer index.

The problem lies in `content = [index for index in content if index not in remove_indices]` which needs to go through `len(remove_indices) * len(content)` number of checks with each iteration. This would take forever (tqdm is telling me 100h+). Any tips on how to speed this up?

**What I've tried so far**

- Taking advantage of the fact that if the words has frequency 1 or 2 only, we can remove it from `remove_indices` after it has been removed from the corpus. Still taking forever...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `numpy.isin()` method https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html instead of this list comprehension.

Alternatively, you could create a `set` of existing words/indices. Then this `in` operation will be a O(1) instead of O(n) (where n is the length of the array).

Comment: Amazing, what is this sorcery? Any resources on how this works mathematically?

Comment: I actually modify the answer, I believe numpy.isin is preferable solution. About set/list time complexity, see for example https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity, more general https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best,_worst_and_average_case (python `set` is a flavor of the hash table.)